# Sum of file sizes with awk on a list of files

Tags: bash, awk

I have a list of files and want to sum over their file sizes.
So, I created a (global) variable as counter and are trying to loop over that list, get the file size with ls and cut&add it with

```
export COUNTER=1
for x in $(cat ./myfiles.lst); do ls -all $x | awk '{COUNTER+=$5}'; done
```

However, my counter is empty?

```
> echo $COUNTER
> 1
```

Does someone has an idea for my, what I am missing here?

Cheers and thanks,
  Thomas

---

OK, I found a way piping the result from the awk pipe into a variable
(which is probably not elegant but working ;) )

```
for x in $(cat ./myfiles.lst); do a=$(ls -all $x |awk '{print $5}'); COUNTER=$(($COUNTER+$a)) ; done

> echo $COUNTER
> 4793061514
```

Comment: instead of `ls -all $x |awk '{print $5}` use `stat -c %s %x`

Answer (score 7):

`awk` is getting called for every file, so in `COUNTER` you got the last file's size.

A better solution is:

```
ls -all <myfiles.lst | awk '{COUNTER+=$5} END {print COUNTER}'
```

But you are reinventing the wheel here. You can do something like

```
du -s <myfiles.lst
```

(If you have `du` installed. *Note*: see the comments below my answer about `du`. I had tested this with `cygwin` and with that it worked like a charm.)

Comment: `du` command I have on `ubuntu 13.10` does not accept anything on `stdin`. It always uses current directory, if FILES parameter is not given.

Comment: Ah, I had not thought about du -- however I get quite diffrerent results between your apporaches 

 ls -all <  /myfiles.lst  | awk '{COUNTER+=$5} END {print COUNTER}'
90523640

du -s < /myfiles.lst
226176

Comment: This can help: `du -c $(cat ./myfiles.lst) | awk 'END{print $1}'` (Assuming no spaces in filenames :))

Comment: OR better: `du -c --files0-from=<(tr '\n' '\0' < ./myfiles.lst) | awk 'END{print $1}'`

Comment: A tiny additional note regarding `du` for those who wind up here from google: add `-h` to make the output human-readable, e.g. using units like 1KB instead of 1000.

Answer (score 5):

Shorter version of the last:

```
ls -l | awk '{sum += $5} END {print sum}'
```

Now, say you want to filter by certain types of files, age, etc... Just throw the ls -l into a find, and you can filter using find's extensive filter parameters:

```
find . -type f -exec ls -l {} \; | awk '{sum += $5} END {print sum}'
```

Comment: If I was trying to teach someone how to use awk this would be the example I would start with.

Answer (score 0):

```
ls -ltS | awk -F " " {'print $5'} | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'
```